# Map LocalStorage to Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm retrieving an object from local storage:

```
 retrieveToken(): JwtToken {
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(_key));
 }
```

I need to map the data stored in local storage to my interface

```
export interface JwtToken {
  access_token: string;
  expires_in: number;
  token_type: string;
  refresh_token: string;
}
```

I've tried:

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(_key) as JwtToken);

return JSON.parse<JwtToken>(localStorage.getItem(_key));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does _key have? Could you share an example

Comment: it's just the string value of the key which it's saved against in localstorage

const AuthStorageKey = 'randomKey';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're performing your cast on the string value retrieved from storage instead of casting the result of `JSON.parse()`.

It should be:

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(_key)) as JwtToken;
```

To get rid of the error caused by the fact that `localStorage.getItem()` potentially returns `null`, you can add a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to convince the compiler that the value for `_key` will definitely be present in `localStorage`:

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(_key)!) as JwtToken;
```

Or, better yet, perform an explicit null check:

```
const jwtTokenString = localStorage.getItem(_key);

if (jwtTokenString) {
    return JSON.parse(jwtTokenString) as JwtToken;
}
```

Comment: I was close with the as JwtToken just needed it outside the brackets ha ha.  I am getting this error: 
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Yeah, need to add a null check. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, one thing though, if jwtTokenString is null then I'd need to return an empty JwtToken because as it stands it currently complains saying Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

Comment: Then change your return type: `retrieveToken(): JwtToken | undefined { /* ... */ }`. Otherwise you'd have to define what an empty JwtToken looks like.